# Closed form of a type of generalised exponential functions

Tags: taylor-series

Let a generalised exponential function exp_{m,n} (I'm not sure if this notation is already used by anything else) be defined as such, for n a positive integer and m between 0 and n-1 (inclusive):

exp_{m,n} (x) = sum of (x^(nk+m)/(nk+m)!) as k ranges from 0 to infinity.

(e.g., cosh = exp_{0,2}, sinh = exp_{1,2}.) What are the closed forms for such generalised exponentials (for arbitrary n) in terms of real transformations of the elementary functions? Using e^(ωx) (where ω is a primitive cube root of 1) a closed form for exp_{1,3} - exp_{2,3} can be obtained, but I'm not sure about the individual functions.

Answer (score 7):

The general closed form is a sum of linear combinations of terms of the form e^{zeta x} where zeta is an nth root of unity.  One way to see this is that f = exP_{m,n} satisfies the differential equation f^{(n)} = f.  If you'd like to look up exactly what this linear combination is, the keyword is "discrete Fourier transform."

Answer (score 1):

This can be done starting with any power series and is called
[series multisection](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SeriesMultisection.html).

Answer (score 0):

The differential equation given by Qiaochu f<sup>(n)</sup> = f can be solved by means of the Laplace transform. We obtain:

s<sup>n</sup>F(s)-s<sup>(n-m-1)</sup> = F(s)

The second term originates from the unvanishing m-th derivative of f(x). All other derivatives up to (n-1) vanish.

Applying the inverse Laplace transform, one finds that the coefficient of exp(ω<sub>i</sub>x) in the expansion is:

ω<sub>i</sub><sup>(-m-1)</sup>/i, where ω<sub>i</sub> is the i-th n-th root of unity

Answer (score 0):

Ricatti seems to have studied the "[generalized hyperbolic functions](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GeneralizedHyperbolicFunctions.html)" way way back, and there's also the Mittag-Leffler function (your original function is expressible in terms of Mittag-Leffler) that frequently crops up in the fractional calculus. You might want to try searching for papers on these things.